# "Connection Must be Valid and Open" Error in C#, MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I am working on a project for work and have been getting a `Connection must be valid and open` error. The error comes during a nested `for` loop.  It looks at each store number and uses the number as a parameter to retrieve information from the database.

The problem I'm having is that the code errors out after the first number is passed. I've tried individually plugging in the store codes to find out if "02" was the only one that worked, and I've found that all of the numbers in the 40 range work as well.

I've checked the state of the connection and it tells me that it is open each time it tries to run through.  I've read that this should mean that it is an error with the SQL then.  I checked that with my boss and he looked at it and told me the SQL was alright.

I am very much hoping someone can help me out here. I've provided the array where the store numbers are located, the nested for loop, the code where we create the SQL, and the code where the SQL is passed to the database below.  Thanks in advance to whomever helps!!

String array of store numbers

```
String[] stores = new String[] { "02", "03", "05", "08", "11", "15", "30", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "06" };
```

Nested 'for' loop

```
for (int questionsCycle = 0; questionsCycle < questions.Length; questionsCycle++)
{
    for (int storeCycle = 0; storeCycle < stores.Length; storeCycle++)
    {
        DataTable dbTable4 =    getSurveys.GetCustomerEmailSurveyResultsForFlagStoreAndDates("C", stores[storeCycle], DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString(), DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString()); //The method that gives me the error
        for (int surveysCycle = 0; surveysCycle < dbTable4.Rows.Count; surveysCycle++)
        {
            DataRow dbRow4 = dbTable4.Rows[surveysCycle];
            runningTotal += Convert.ToInt16(dbRow4[questions[questionsCycle]].ToString());
            dbRow4 = null;
        }

        if (runningTotal != 0)
        {
            data[questionsCycle, storeCycle] = dbTable4.Rows.Count.ToString() + "/" + ((double)runningTotal / dbTable4.Rows.Count).ToString("#0.00");
            questionTotals[questionsCycle, storeCycle] = (double)runningTotal / dbTable4.Rows.Count;
            questionRows[questionsCycle, storeCycle] = dbTable4.Rows.Count;
        }
        companyTotal += runningTotal;
        surveyTotal += dbTable4.Rows.Count;
        runningTotal = 0;
        dbTable4 = null;
    }
```

The method that creates the SQL in our Data Manager:

```
public DataTable GetCustomerEmailSurveyResultsForFlagStoreAndDates(string flag, string strStore, string strBegDate, string strEndDate)
    {
        string strSQL = "select * from customer_email_survey";
        strSQL += " where sent_date between '" + strBegDate + "' and '" + strEndDate + "'";
        //added by cjc on 5/31/13...sales leaders change for customer experiecne results
        if (flag == "Experience")
        {
            strSQL += " and (flag = 'D' OR flag = 'P')";
        }
        else
        {
            strSQL += " and flag = '" + flag + "'";
        }
        if (strStore == "MATT")
        {
            strStore = "41', '42', '43', '44', '46', '47', '48', '49', '61";
        }
        strSQL += " and store_code in ('" + strStore + "'";
        switch (strStore)
        {
            case "11":
                strSQL += ", '12')";
                break;
            case "15":
                strSQL += ", '16')";
                break;
            case "08":
                strSQL += ", '22')";
                break;
            case "30":
                strSQL += ", '31')";
                break;
            default:
                strSQL += ")";
                break;
        }
        DataTable dbTable = this.GetData(strSQL);
        return dbTable;
    }
```

The method that connects to the database and passes the sql

```
private DataTable GetData(string strSQL)
{
    MySqlConnection dbConn = new MySqlConnection(strConnectionString);
    MySqlDataAdapter dbAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL,dbConn);
    DataSet dbSet = new DataSet();
    dbAdapter.Fill(dbSet); //The line where the code bombs 
    DataTable dbTable = new DataTable();
    dbTable = dbSet.Tables[0];
    dbAdapter = null;
    dbSet = null;
    dbConn.Close();
    return dbTable;
}
```

This is what I got from my stack trace (if I did it correctly):

> SendCustomerSurveyResults at offset 3802 in file:line:column C:\Dev\legacy\CustomerEmail\CustomerEmailProgram.cs:31175:25
>   CustomerEmailProgram_Load at offset 120 in file:line:column C:\Dev\legacy\CustomerEmail\CustomerEmailProgram.cs:68:17
>   OnLoad at offset 373 in file:line:column :0:0
>   CreateControl at offset 434 in file:line:column :0:0
>   CreateControl at offset 36 in file:line:column :0:0
>   WmShowWindow at offset 221 in file:line:column :0:0
>   WndProc at offset 1087 in file:line:column :0:0
>   WndProc at offset 70 in file:line:column :0:0
>   DebuggableCallback at offset 173 in file:line:column :0:0
>   SetVisibleCore at offset 334 in file:line:column :0:0
>   SetVisibleCore at offset 384 in file:line:column :0:0
>   RunMessageLoopInner at offset 491 in file:line:column :0:0
>   RunMessageLoop at offset 101 in file:line:column :0:0
>   Main at offset 67 in file:line:column C:\Dev\legacy\CustomerEmail\CustomerEmailProgram.cs:632:13
>   _nExecuteAssembly at offset 0 in file:line:column :0:0
>   RunUsersAssembly at offset 71 in file:line:column :0:0
>   Run at offset 155 in file:line:column :0:0
>   ThreadStart at offset 77 in file:line:column :0:0

Comment: `DataAdapter` would open the connection implicitly, So there must be something wrong with your connection string. Make sure you are passing the right credentials.

Comment: The getSurveys object is used once before it is in the code above and works fine, so the connection string should be fine. It also goes through the loop once and only errors out once it gets to the second number in the array

Comment: Off topic:  you really need to look into parameterized queries:  http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/

Comment: And post a stack trace of the exception you are receiving.

Comment: This is for my internship, so the sql was already in place. The only time we don't used parameterized queries is when we're working with MySQL. And I'm not sure how to get a stack trace of the exception to post for you. I'm still fairly new to this stuff.

Comment: @DonBoitnott, I've added my stack trace. If I've done it correctly, what is it telling me that is wrong?